# Wired video door bell camera - voltage/transformer questions

Tags: wiring, doorbell

I'm trying to install a Eufy dual video doorbell camera, wired.
I came up to a snag when I tried to verify my voltage output.
This camera requires 16-24V 30VA output. Looking at my transformer in my chime, it says power output is 16V 10VA, so I guess my transformer (voltage * amps) is too low.

[image]

However, even before I figured out to VA number is wrong, I am unable to get a multimeter voltage reading of 16V. I only get about half of that. But I am not sure if I am measuring correctly. My door bell wires are yellow and red. Why is there 5 different wire colors here? I know one is ground but others don't make sense. I measured voltage drop across yellow/red and that's about 8V. Same thing between blue and green.

[image]

what is the easiest way to hook up my camera? Should I buy one of these [transformers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Newhouse-Hardware-Wired-16V-30vA-Doorbell-Transformer-Compatible-with-Ring-Pro-30TR/307787405)?  But then I don't know what to do with my existing door bell box. I'd like to keep something there just in case I sell the house and want to take my camera with me. I also don't want to be patching up a wall.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. You're asking many questions here. While they're related, you should take the [tour], then see if you can revise to simplify to one question. Also, post photos here using the editor rather than just linking us to another site.

Comment: The voltage divides between the front and rear button's light bulbs, so expect half the voltage at the chime. Your transformer is not in that box, which you should keep intact; thus upgrading the transformer won't affect your front hall at all. The linked transformer seems up to the job, but maybe your current one is already sufficient, post a picture of it, usually in the basement or a closet connected to mains and those bell wires. You might also have to replace the rear button with a dumb (no light) button so that it doesn't drop the voltage provided to the camera.

Comment: Based on the photo, there's no rear button

Comment: If the camera doorbell is anything like the one I installed two days ago, there's a shunt device between the trans and front connections to be placed inside the chime box. It allows the existing chime to continue to be used with the new camera button.

Comment: @fred_dot_u sure it's a shunt? I would expect that to keep the chime from powering. Is it a diode (a little black cylinder with a silver stipe around one end)?

Comment: The manual describes it as a shunt and it's "potted" in such a way as to prevent viewing of the internals. With the shunt in place, pressing the doorbell camera button causes the original chime to sound, but it also allowed the original doorbell button to sound the chime while it was in place. This is a Kuna doorbell, perhaps previously known as a Maximus. Other systems may be different, but one can usually find installation manuals online.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your doorbell chime box it will work fine with the new transformer. Basically the transformer is directly wired to your electrical panel which is high voltage the wire from the transformer to your chime is converted to low voltage and the wiring from the chime to the outside is low voltage as well. 16v-24v gives the video doorbell enough voltage allowing the camera to work properly but if your voltage is below 16v your camera will have choppy video to no video at all. You don't have to replace the wires just the transformer and you will be fine. Just remember to turn your doorbell system off at the electrical panel before you replace your transformer.